# Is my Relation Algebra correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I am trying to understand Relation Algebra for my Database Class and I was wondering if someone here can look at what I've done and help me figure out what is correct and what isnt.

What I am trying to solve is: For each department, retrieve the name and the min and max salary range for every employee in that department.

Table Setup:

```
Employee(Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno)
Department(Dname, Dnumber, Mgr_ssn, Mgr_start_date)
```

SQL:

```
Select Dname, Min(Salary), Max(Salary)    
from EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT    
Where Dnumber = Dno    
Group by Dname
```

Relational Algebra (Step, with one operand per line):

- Salaries ← π(Dno, Salary)[EMPLOYEE]
- Departments ← π(Dname, Dnumber)[DEPARTMENT]
- SalariesD ← Salaries JOIN(Symbol wont work)(Dno=Dnumber) Departments
- Selection ← π(Dname, Min(Salary), Max(Salary))[SalariesD]
- Results ← Group-Symbol(Dname)[Selection]

Sorry about the formatting. Please let me know if im on the right track with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be also right......

```
select a.Fname,Max(a.Salary),Min(a.Salary)
from Employee a
join Department b on a.Dno = b.Dnumber
group by Dname
```